# How to inverse data to original data values in order to get accurate MSE value?

Tags: python

Instead of the min-max scale, the following code was used to normalize the data. But I need to convert data back to the original value. Please how can I invert it?

```
train_mean = train_data.mean()
train_std = train_data.std()

train_data = (train_data - train_mean) / train_std
val_data = (val_data - train_mean) / train_std
test_da

ta = (test_data - train_mean) / train_std
```

the complete example code can be found here. but no inverse was made for evaluation performance
https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/structured_data/time_series

Comment: Have tried to inverse the formulas ?

Comment: try to reverse operations can replacing minus with plus and divide with multiply help i.e train_data = (train_data + train_mean)  *  train_std

Comment: Thank you #manu190466. I had tried it before posting this question but it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

normalized_data = (data-mean)/std

data = normalized_data x std + mean

```
import numpy as np

train_data = np.random.uniform(size=(100))

train_mean = train_data.mean()
train_std = train_data.std()

normalized_train_data = (train_data - train_mean) / train_std
recovered_train_data = normalized_train_data*train_std + train_mean

np.isclose(recovered_train_data, train_data).all()

#True
```